# Loading form input values from web pages into URLRequest?

Tags: iphone, post, nsurlconnection, urlrequest

How would I pull out the form values for the html source below and add them to an NSURLConnection?

```
<tr>
                            <th><label for="username"><span class="accesskey">N</span>etID:</label></th>
                            <td><input id="username" name="username" class="required" tabindex="1" accesskey="n" type="text" value="" size="32" autocomplete="false"/></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <th><label for="password"><span class="accesskey">P</span>assword:</label></th>
                            <td><input id="password" name="password" class="required" tabindex="2" accesskey="p" type="password" value="" size="32"/></td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <th><label for="authenticationType"><span class="accesskey">A</span>uthentication Type:</label></th>
                            <td>
                               <select id="authenticationType" name="authenticationType">
                                  <option value="Kerberos">Default</option>
                                  <option value="SafeWord">SafeWord</option>
                               </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="warn" name="warn" value="true" tabindex="3" />
                                <label for="warn" class="other" accesskey="w"><span class="accesskey">W</span>arn me before logging me into other sites.</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr><tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" name="_currentStateId" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
                                <input type="submit" accesskey="l" value="LOGIN" tabindex="4" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: so you've got a chunk of HTML, I'm confused what you need to do  Are you supposed to read the form fields (since no values have been entered yet by the user)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [elementParser](http://touchtank.wordpress.com/element-parser/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the HTML is also valid XML, you can run the whole thing through an NSXMLParser (or other XML-parsing code) and perform some action whenever it detects an element that is a form input (such as `<input>`).

Otherwise, you might be better off just writing your own string-parsing function(s) - look for any instance of the tag you want to grab, pull all the text between the < and > characters, split it by spaces, and then find the name of the input field so you can put it into an NSURLConnection.